# Select max of each record group by name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with several columns:

```
Name  Price    Date   ...
a     100      .....
b     110      .....
c     90       .....
a     130      .....
b     60       .....
d     200      .....
c     5        .....
```

I want to write a query that will give me Max Price of each Name:

```
a   130     .....
b   110     .....
c   90      .....
d   200     .....
```

Comment: HINT: You need `GROUP BY` for a start...

Comment: For your required output, there are ..... as 3rd column. Do we have a 3rd column?

Comment: yes,have more than 3

Comment: All other columns have different values? eg. different dates for name `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    
        (
          SELECT *, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name 
                                    ORDER BY Name ASC, Price DESC) AS RN
          FROM  Table
        ) AS T
WHERE   RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT tbl1.* FROM table_1 tbl1 INNER JOIN(
    SELECT name,MAX(price) price FROM table_1 GROUP BY name) tbl2
        ON tbl1.name = tbl2.name AND tbl1.price = tbl2.price
```

code reformed ;)

Comment: What about `Date` column?

Comment: @Jesuraja , the question asked it and this query will do it

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as(
    select
        rn = row_number() over(partition by Name order by Price desc),
        *
    from <table name>
)
select
    <columns>
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it better to do it by a **self-join**:

- At first, the inner query prepared a list of `Name1` and `Name2` that has the same `Name` but their `Price`'s are different,
- Then, group by `Name` to find out the maximum Price of each `Name` by max()

**Query:**

```
select Name1, max(Price1)

(
    select
        tbl1.Name Name1, tbl1.Price Price1,
        tbl2.Name Name2, tbl2.Price Price2
    from TableName tbl1 left join TableName tbl2
        on tbl1.Name = tbl2.Name
        and tbl1.Price != tbl2.Price
)ds
group by Name1
```

**Output**

```
Name  |  Price
---------------
a     |  130
b     |  110
c     |  90
d     |  200
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select Name, Price, Date from (select max(Price)as p, Name as n from TableName 
group by Name) as A 
inner join 
(select * from from TableName where A.p=price and A.n=Name) as B
```

Try this one.

Comment: What about `Date` column?

Comment: it has more than two or three columns